# Why mysql table info shows data free only 5 MB but optimize table reduced table size from 800GB to 1 GB?

Tags: mysql

My question is purely about mysql. I have a wordpress application. My application database has a table named wp_options which grows very fast. This is a InnoDB table. My table size grew to 800 GB while mysqldump of table was less than 1 GB. This made me suspicious that table is fragmented due to frequent delete and updates. When I ran "optimize table" it reduced the size of table to 1 GB so my analysis also seemed to be correct.

My problem is with table info. Table info showed that 'Data length' was 800GB and 'Data free'  was only 5 MB. As per mysql Table info there was no fragmentation. The result of following query was also similar -

```
select ENGINE, TABLE_NAME,Round( DATA_LENGTH/1024/1024) as data_length , round(INDEX_LENGTH/1024/1024) as index_length, round(DATA_FREE/ 1024/1024) as data_free from information_schema.tables  where  DATA_FREE > 0 and TABLE_NAME='wp_options';
```

> ENGINE, TABLE_NAME, data_length, index_length, data_free
> 'InnoDB', 'wp_options','812128','2','5'

does it mean Table info is misleading and incorrect here? If yes then how does one really know if table is fragmented?

Comment: The 800 GB produced by mysqldump belong to SQL code. SQL code will typically be larger than the binary storage resulting from it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález:  OP states that size of mysqldump output is **1** GB not **800** GB.  What's not clear is how OP determined that "optimize table" reduced the size of the table to 1GB, when information_schema is showing size as 800 GB...  I think the issue has more to do with innodb_stats_persistent , innodb_stats_on_metadata (if table is innodb not myisam)  ...  also not clear there aren't two (or more) wp_options tables, the query shown is reporting size in MB ( /1024/1024) and not GB ... only a sketchy overview provided, and not actual query results, or evidence of size of the table ...

Comment: @spencer7593, information_schema started showing the size as 1 GB after running "optimize table " . table is innodb. there is only one wp_options table. the query shows size in MB but the query output was 800,000 MB .